# Unable to drag and drop GLTF file with separate textures in tauri app

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, gltf, tauri

I am making a tauri app, in which I am trying to drag and drop .gltf file into the app.
But I am getting this error

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://asset.localhost/D%3A%5CProjects%5CTemp%5CSparkAR%5CMagical_Cult%5Cobjects%5Cscene%5Cscene.bin'
> from origin 'http://localhost:1420' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>
> GET
> https://asset.localhost/D%3A%5CProjects%5CTemp%5CSparkAR%5CMagical_Cult%5Cobjects%5Cscene%5Cscene.bin
> net::ERR_FAILED

The 3d model has a separate folder containing the textures and a separate .bin file

```
"buffers": [
    {
      "byteLength": 324816,
      "uri": "scene.bin"
    }
  ],
  "images": [
    {
      "uri": "textures/branches_baseColor.png"
    },
    {
      "uri": "textures/branches_normal.png"
    },
    {
      "uri": "textures/tree2_metallicRoughness.png"
    },
    {
      "uri": "textures/tree2_normal.png"
    },
    {
      "uri": "textures/tree2_baseColor.png"
    }
  ],
```

In my loadGltf function I have added a setURLModifier callback function to the loading manager

```
const gltfLoader = (fileInfo: any, scene: any) => {
  const fileName = fileInfo.name;
  const filePath = fileInfo.path;
  const manager = new LoadingManager();
  manager.setURLModifier((url) => {
    return convertFileSrc(url);
  });
  const loader = new GLTFLoader(manager);
  console.log(fileInfo);

  loader.setResourcePath(filePath.split(fileName)[0]);
    
  loader.load(
    filePath,
    (gltf) => {
      scene.add(gltf.scene);
    },
    undefined,
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
};
```

This does not cause any issue when I am loading a .glb file.

Comment: This is a CORS error, nothing to do with 3D or WebGL or glTF.  https://enable-cors.org/  Basically, `localhost:1420` is not the "same origin" as `asset.localhost`, so there are extra steps to configure the web server correctly.

Comment: @emackey But when I am trying to load a glb file I am not getting this error - the converted file path for the glb is `https://asset.localhost/D%3A%5CProjects%5CTemp%5CSparkAR%5CMagical_Cult%5Cobjects%5Cgallery%20fbx(2)%5Cgallery%20fbx.glb`

I am getting this error for gltf files and only for the textures and the bin file as they are referenced inside the gltf file.

Comment: You can't fetch a glTF, nor any other kind of file or web response, from a different "origin" than where your page is running.  If you try, the browser thinks it's a security violation of a type known as CORS.  Your server hosting `asset.localhost` needs to be configured to [enable CORS](https://enable-cors.org/) to work around this, unless you can move the file onto the same development server as the page. This is a common problem, mentioned directly in your error message above, and you'll need to research it to understand the details.